# Attempting to Switch from MariaDB FKM to Hashicorp Vault Key Management

Tags: mariadb, encryption, galera

I've been trying for a good few months now to switch our MariaDB 10.5-Enterprise servers over from File Key Management to Hashicorp Vault key management.
We have 13 'regions' each with 3 MDB servers in a galera-4 cluster, current encrypted using AES-CTR algorithm, the issue here is HCV uses AES-CBC so I need to decrypt the data and then re-encrypt it. We set the Hashicorp key to match the current encryption key for the database so a seamless switchover is possible.

Update - 21/02/24 11:50

Attempted to decrypt and re-encrypt using a mariadbackup sent from the live cluster without activating p/s replication, failed with the same error as before.

In a test environment we followed the below procedure and everything worked fine:

1. Decrypt data in the Database
2. Change mariadb.cnf file to reflect using AES_CBC, still using FKM for now and restart the database.
3. Once data had re-encrypted, change over the plugin in the mariadb.cnf file to HCV.
4. Restart MDB again and at this point the DB server came back online and everything was fine, showing it was using HCV and we could even rotate the keys in the HCV gui.

Now when this was tried on a live environment, we got to the point of re-encrypting the data using AES_CBC and was presented with the following error:

2024-01-30 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to read page 56067 from file './db/table.ibd': Table is encrypted but decrypt failed.
2024-01-30 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The page [page id: space=161, page number=56092] in file './db/table.ibd' cannot be decrypted.
2024-01-30 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: However key management plugin or used key_version 1 is not found or used encryption algorithm or method does not match.
2024-01-30 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Marking tablespace as missing. You may drop this table or install correct key management plugin and key file.

(I have changed the DB and table names for security).

We thought this might be because of live data still being pumped into the database, so since then we have tried stopping the application, same error, stopping the application and removing the node from the cluster and trying the same process...same error.

Last night I tried to create 3 completely new servers, set one of them as a primary/secondary replica to the unencrypted live database, and tried to encrypt it directly to HCV...again the same error.

I'm at my wits end now! Any advice would be greatly appreciated, MDB enterprise support have not been very helpful as they have never attempted this themselves.

If you need more info let me know, first time posting so might have missed things.

Comment: It seems that you have an enterprise version of the service. I suggest that they deal with this problem.